# Does anyone have an example of PrestaSharp how to add products?

Tags: prestashop-1.7

**Hello**

I am using presta sharp to star a new project of webservice with prestashop, does anybody have a code on c# of how to add a product?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

just look at https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/559930-c-how-send-a-new-product/ you have an example how you can push product with webservice in C#